# Java help - StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, prolog, interprolog

I'm having trouble with some of my code and I really cant trouble shoot this error.

I'm using Interprolog(Java+Prolog) see [here](http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/)

here is the stacktrace:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at      com.declarativa.interprolog.AbstractPrologEngine.copyToTemp(AbstractPrologEngine.java)
 at com.declarativa.interprolog.AbstractPrologEngine.consultFromPackage(AbstractPrologEngine.java)
 at LoginHandler.actionPerformed(LoginHandler.java:24)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and the code in question:

```
      myEngine = new NativeEngine();
  myEngine.consultFromPackage("C:\\interprolog212a\\userlist.p", LoginHandler.class);
  boolean x = myEngine.deterministicGoal("hasAccess(user,pass)");
```

any ideas? I'm hitting a brickwall...

oh and line 24 is the second line of code i posted.

edit: content of userlist.p:

```
hasAccess(tom,123).
hasAccess(bob,456).
```

following on from some of the suggestions below, i moved loginhandler and related classes to their own package and also userlist.p to the package, and now i get this error:

```
com.declarativa.interprolog.util.IPException: Problem consulting from package         archive:C:\Users\Keval\AppData\Local\Temp\IP_5283895338735856757\userlist.p
```

Comment: What does userList.pl look like?  My only guess is that somehow hasAccess(user,pass) doesn't play nice with whatever's in that file.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply. I have edited the original post and you can now see the contents of userlist.pl.

cheers

Comment: Do you  have access to the source code for NativeEngine to see what it is trying to get a substring of and how it is getting the index for the substring?

Comment: i do, i think but how would i do that? break point?

Comment: actually it looks like i do not have access to the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay for open source I suppose. It's doing this:

```
String className = rc.getName();    
String packageName = className.substring(0,className.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

`rc` is your calling class. So I suppose your `LoginHandler` class is in the default package and that is tripping this code up? Try putting it in a package, i.e. add `package blah;` to the top of it and move it to a directory with that name.

It does this because it assumes the `userlist.pl` is actually in the same location as your code and it's trying to use the package name to find the location your code was loaded from. I don't think you can use `consultFromPackage()` the way you are trying to actually, since it supposedly can only parse a filename, not a full blown path.

Oh and you can get the source. It's in the [zip file](http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/interprolog212.zip) linked from [the website](http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/INSTALL.htm).

Comment: hi there. I have also tried ConsultFromPackage(userlist.pl, class) as the pl file is indeed in the same package/dir as the java files/code location.

Comment: @keval You might have missed my second edit. Try putting `LoginHandler` in a package. I assume it's currently in the default package (i.e. no package declaration at the top).

Comment: I have moved it to its own package now, will let you know what happens.

Comment: Right, moved both the consulting file(userlist.pl) and the loginhandler to its own package, now getting this error:

com.declarativa.interprolog.util.IPException: Problem consulting from package archive:C:\Users\Keval\AppData\Local\Temp\IP_5283895338735856757\userlist.p

Answer (score 0):

Is the second `\\` in the path confusing it? If it's doing anything to examine each directory in the path it could be confused by an empty string, maybe?